# How do I remove this "overlay" in the bottom navigation view (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

The following behavior only shows during run time

[Image Showing unwanted bottom navigation view behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTeB4.png)

the xml code for the above is:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:background="#92000000"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a drawable resource file with a transparent rectangle and use it as view background

transparent_rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#92000000" />

</shape>
```

and your view should be

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/transparent_rectangle"
android:layout_height="70dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu" />
```